# How can i access my domain name DNS info from a rogue registrar

Tags: dns

Im having trouble getting my domain name DNS info from a terrible registrar i've used for the last 3 years. Long story short i chose not to renew my reseller hosting account and he's now withholding access to my domain name which i registered through his site also. I need to point the primary & secondary names to my new VPS at another company.  When i 'Whois' my domain name i see its pointing to generic parking page.

**My question : is it my old registrars responsibility to give me access to the Prim/Sec name servers via a control panel (which his website blurb says is availabe to 'domain-name only' customers) or should i contact internic who manage .net names?  Here is a cut 'n paste of a portion of the whois info :**

> Referral URL: http://www.publicdomainregistry.com Name Server:
>   DNS10.PARKPAGE.FOUNDATIONAPI.COM Name Server:
>   DNS11.PARKPAGE.FOUNDATIONAPI.COM Status: clientTransferProhibited
>   https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited Updated Date:
>   25-jan-2017 Creation Date: 24-jan-2014 Expiration Date: 24-jan-2018

BTW: when he last answered my support ticket he didnt even know that i had renewed the domain name for another 12 months BEFORE it expired. After i pointed it out and asked for access to the DNS servers via a control panel he's stopped answering my support tickets

Answer (score 0):

If a registrar is behaving badly, then you can turn to the registry for help, yes.